# Playing multiple videos JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am totally new on JavaFx, I have a vbox with 3 ToggleButtons, When I click a Button a video will start playing on an another layout with 3 columns so I can play 3 videos on that layout by clicking the 3 ToggleButtons. I didn't found any help with tutorials. Can anyone suggest how to do it?
Here's my 3 buttons code

```
   private static Scene createScene() {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // Création du layout pour les vidéos ainsi que du media builder pour
    // construire les vidéos
    VBox gridpane = new VBox(0.4);

    gridpane.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    gridpane.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid;"
                + "-fx-border-width: 1;"
                + "-fx-border-color: black");
    Image progress = new Image(mediaplayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/cameras_images/im1.jpg"));
    Image im2 = new Image(mediaplayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/cameras_images/im2.jpg"));
    Image im3 = new Image(mediaplayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/cameras_images/im3.jpg"));


    ToggleButton bouton1 = new ToggleButton(" 1      ",new ImageView(progress));
      bouton1.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
    ToggleButton bouton2 = new ToggleButton(" 2                 ",new ImageView(im2));
    bouton2.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
    bouton2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);


    ToggleButton bouton3 = new ToggleButton(" 3                                                           ",new ImageView(im3));
    bouton3.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

    bouton3.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

     gridpane.getChildren().add(bouton1); 
     gridpane.getChildren().add(bouton2);  
     gridpane.getChildren().add(bouton3); 


    root.getChildren().add(gridpane);


    return (scene);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now the buttons do nothing. You need to add listeners to the buttons so that an action is triggered when the user toggles the buttons. Like so:

```
bouton1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

        //if button is selected, start video
        //if button is deselected, stop video
    }
});
```

Comment: I know that, my problem is how to set the video to play in the right place

Comment: Oh! http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/simpleplayer.htm read that. You need a MediaPlayer object (which wraps the stream) and as MediaView object (that shows the stream). Add the MediaView component to your UI. Then control both of those with your buttons.